# How to go combine for loop and regex?

Tags: python, regex, loops

I have a SQL table as shown below

[image: Screenshot of table](Can't directly post image because of insufficient reputation)

And I am trying to classify the different words as nouns, adverbs, adjectives etc (One word can have multiple classifications like the word "Abandon" in this screenshot). I have another table in this same DB which I have loaded as a list in my program.

Using nested for loops and regex, I am trying to get the type of word it is. Here's my code

```
# Defining the function
def typ_fun(defin,regex):
    p = re.compile('regex[0]')
    match = re.search(p, str(defin[1]))
    if match:
        print(defin[0], defin[1])

#cur_1. is the cursor to connect to the SQL Table   and lst is the list 
cur_1.execute('''SELECT id,definition FROM Words''')
for row in cur_1:
    for a in lst:
        typ_fun(row, a)
```

But it is not matching anything at all.

Basically what I want to do is write a **combination of for loop and regex** where the regex is each time an item from the list which should then be searched for in the definition column row-wise. My list looks like this

```
lst = [ prefix, suffix, v., adv., adj., prep.]
```

Giving me a final result of the form

```
ID        WORD        DEFINITION        TYPE
1        abandon      blah blah        v., adj.
2        abandoned    blah blah        adj.
```

Comment: Define `list_of_matches=[]` and the regex as `reg = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})(?!\w)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, lst))))`, then populate it using `for row in cur_1: list_of_matches.append(reg.findall(str(row[1])))`  and then assign the list to the table, or just populate it when looping. Please let know if it helps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks and it works brilliantly. So I am new to python and am unable to understand what this is doing. Can you help me with it?
Also, in the for loop I have added this to get the id of the row```print(row[0], list_of_matches[row[0]-1])```.  Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: If it works, yes, indexing is a good way to access list data. Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

```
list_of_matches=[]
reg = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})(?!\w)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, lst))))
```

The regex will look like `\b(?:prefix|suffix|v\.|adv\.|adj\.|prep\.)(?!\w)`, see how it works in the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/1mhxLr/1). It matches all these terms from your list if they are not enclosed with letters, digits or underscores.

Then populate the `list_of_matches` using

```
for row in cur_1:
    list_of_matches.append(reg.findall(str(row[1])))
```

Then assign the list to the table, or just populate it when looping.